# pyspark sql combine two columns with same value but different names

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have two tables with below structure

Table1

```
lang created_date
java 11-01-23
python 11-11-23
```

Table2

```
lang ingested_date
scala 11-21-23
```

I want to create combined table with expected result:

Table3

```
lang created_date
java 11-01-23
python 11-11-23
scala 11-21-23
```

Actual Result

```
lang created_date
java 11-01-23
python 11-11-23
scala 11-21-23
scala null
```

I am using below python pyspark code but it is giving me additional row with null value in created_date column.

```
table1DF = sparkSession.read.table("Table1")
table2DF = sparkSession.read.table("Table2")

table1 = table1DF.col("lang").col("created_date")
table2 = table2DF.col("lang").col("ingested_date").alias("created_date")

merged_table = table1.union(table2)
final_table = merged_table.groupBy("lang", "created_date")
```

How do I avoid getting the last row with null value in one of the columns when I am combining data from two tables using union?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the coalesce function to select the non-null value from the two columns

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

table1DF = sparkSession.read.table("Table1")
table2DF = sparkSession.read.table("Table2")

table1 = table1DF.select("lang", "created_date")
table2 = table2DF.select("lang", "ingested_date").alias("created_date")

merged_table = table1.union(table2)
final_table = merged_table.groupBy("lang").agg(coalesce("created_date", "ingested_date").alias("created_date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I tested regarding your issue, `union` function doesn't care about the name of columns, it cares about their number and their types, and it stacks data on top of each other, getting the row ('scala', NULL) is weird, since I tested that and it works fine unless you have the row already in table2.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()
# Creating the data sample
schema = StructType([
    StructField("lang", StringType(), True),
    StructField("created_date", StringType(), True)
])
rows = [Row("java", "11-01-23"), Row("python", "11-11-23")]
rows2 = [Row("scala", "11-21-23"), Row("scala", None)]
schema2 = StructType([
    StructField("lang", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ingested_date", StringType(), True)
])

# Creating the dataframes
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows2, schema2)
# Union the dataframes
result = df.union(df2)
result.dropna().show()
```

even column2 in table1 `created_date` and column2 in table2 is called `ingested_date`, `union` will stack the data since it checks the number of columns of the dataframes and the type of each column.

Regarding your code, it is not reproducible, unfortunately. However, in case you still have an extra useless row after executing `union` you could do the following and you will be good:

```
merged_table = table1.union(table2).dropna()
```

curious and open to discussion, I hope this help!